# Copy files from MSBuild folder to Output folder using Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild

Using TFS 2013 and I have files that show up in the `c:\builds` location that need to be copied over to the build output folder once the build is complete. Would like to use powershell to accomplish this while using the `TfvcTemplate.12`.

Below is the closest thing I could find as a reference, but I'm not familiar with powershell, or how to point the `$SrcDir` and `$DestDir` to the `c:\builds` folder since it is never the same or the output folder since it changes as well.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642297/File-copy-using-Microsoft-Powershell

Comment: If by "output folder" you mean a network share that saves the build results, that operation is done by the build workflow template at the very end. Are you using workflow?  You don't mention use the legacy template.

Comment: No, I'm using the default template for TFS 2013 that is listed above. Yes, the build output folder you specify that gets versioned however you specify in the build definition.

Answer (score -1):

I use PowerShell quite a bit in my TeamBuild 2012 (customized) workflow.  You need to create an InvokeProcess activity.  Set it to start PowerShell.exe.  I pass in arguments like:

```
"-NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command ""& {" + SourcesDirectory + "\Common\Build\AuthenticodeSignFiles.ps1 '" + outputDirectory + "'" + " -Verbose:" + PowerShellVerboseSwitchValue + "}"""
```

TeamBuild defines SourcesDirectory, BinariesDirectory and DropLocation which you can pass to PowerShell.  The "Compile and Test for Configuration" activity defines the variable `outputDirectory` which is updated for each config|platform combo it builds.

Comment: I run powershell script already to version the assemblies, but I do not have an InvokeProcess activity to start Powershell.exe.

Comment: Then how are you invoking PowerShell.exe from TeamBuild?  However it is you are doing that, you can pass in variables that are defined by TeamBuild. These include variables like SourcesDirectory and BinariesDirectory.  These variables contain the paths that are correct for the current build.

Comment: I look into the passing in of variables. The newer templates for MSBuild allow you to use scripts without having to customize your build template.

Comment: Keith, the 2013 default templates has built in PowerShell invocation locations for pre/post build and pre/post test.

Comment: Ah, we are still on TFS 2012.  Guess we missed out on that feature.